# Positioning cursor at the end of the text in a RichEdit control

Tags: c++, winapi

I use the following code in an attempt to position the caret at the end of the text in a rich edit control:

```
    int len = GetWindowTextLength(editwin);
    SendMessage(editwin,EM_SETSEL,0,MAKELONG(len,len));
```

Unfortunately it appears to highlight (select) the entirety of the text. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661.aspx) for `EM_SETSEL`:

> **Parameters**
>
> **wParam** The starting character position of the selection.
>
> **lParam** The ending character position of the selection.

So you need to pass `len` to both `wParam` and `lParam`.